# C++ How to call a subclass function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I want to use the derived class `B::display()` and  `C::display()`, but it uses `A::display()`. How do I change the code so that I can call the derived class' `display()` to display the `id` together with `name`?
Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected :
    int id;
public:
    A ( int id = 0 ) : id(id) {}
    virtual void display() { cout << id << endl; }

};

class B : public A
{
    string name;
public:
    B ( int id = 0, string name = "-" ) : A(id), name(name) {}
    void display() { cout << id << " " << name << endl; }
};

class C : public A
{
    string name;
public:
    C ( int id = 0, string name = "-" ) : A(id), name(name) {}
    void display() { cout << id << " " << name << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector< vector <A> > aa;
    vector<A> bb ;
    vector<A> cc ;

    A *yy = new B(111, "Patrick");
    A *zz = new C(222, "Peter");
    bb.push_back(*yy);
    cc.push_back(*zz);

    aa.push_back(bb);
    aa.push_back(cc);

    for ( int i = 0; i < aa[0].size(); i++)
    {
        aa[0][i].display();
        aa[1][i].display();
    }
}
```

Comment: your problem his that you are not saving a pointer in the vector. if you will change the vector to this : vector<A*> it will work.

Comment: I thought the subclass' function will automatically become virtual when I declare it to be virtual in the superclass?

Comment: yeah you are right i didnt notice that your super class display is virtual. i edited my first comment.

Comment: This doesn't affect correctness of your program, but you should also declare your B::display() and C::display() as override (void display() override { ... }). This comes in handy when you get to larger programs.

Comment: @MatthewWoo Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem his that you are declartion of the vector is of non pointer type , and on runtime you are losing the "point" to the subclass and you just stay with the super class.
all you have to do is change all of your vectors to pointer type , like that:

```
vector<A*> bb;
```

Comment: @Jess, this is called slicing. Just get rid of the `*` when you're pushing back and store the pointer rather than the object itself.

Comment: @Daniel Kovachev Thanks for your help!! I managed to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is in order for inheritance to work you need to use pointers.  your vector is a `vector<A>` and not a `vector<A*>` so when you push-back the dereferences version of yy and zz you are pushing back the copy of their A data members not a copy of the B and C data members.  The size of B and C is different then A so it will only do a copy of data members that will fit in the place of A object.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/

Comment: @Jess the only additional link I can think of at the moment would be: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect polymorphism to work without pointers.
Change your main part to

```
vector< vector <A*> > aa;
vector<A*> bb;
vector<A*> cc;

A* yy = new B(111, "Patrick");
A* zz = new C(222, "Peter");
bb.push_back(yy);
cc.push_back(zz);

aa.push_back(bb);
aa.push_back(cc);

for (int i = 0; i < aa[0].size(); i++)
{
    aa[0][i]->display();
    aa[1][i]->display();
}
```